# r: Count number of each value in every column

Tags: r

I am just begining with r and I've been stuggling on how to do a very simple task: count the number of each value in every column of my data. More precisely, my data looks something like this:

|  | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | YES | NO | NO |
| 2 | YES | MAYBE | MAYBE |
| 3 | NO | NO | YES |
| 4 | YES | NO | YES |
| 5 | NO | NO | YES |

And I want it to look like this:

|  | Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| YES | 3 | 0 | 3 |
| MAYBE | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| NO | 2 | 4 | 1 |

using
`table(my.data)`
tells me thatI'm trying to create a table with 2^31 elements and returns an error.

Can someone please help me with that? What's an easy way to do this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Try `table(stack(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your data isn't in long-format.
Try pivoting longer using tidyr, and then calculating a crosstab using `janitor`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_to = "response", names_to = "type") %>%
  tabyl(response, type)
 response Column A Column B Column C
    MAYBE        0        1        1
       NO        2        4        1
      YES        3        0        3
```

## Data

```
df <- structure(list(`Column A` = c("YES", "YES", "NO", "YES", "NO"
), `Column B` = c("NO", "MAYBE", "NO", "NO", "NO"), `Column C` = c("NO", 
"MAYBE", "YES", "YES", "YES")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

To learn a bit more, I'd recommend reading this: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html